# Button give score to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, button

I'm learning html programming and I want to create a "website" (just to try my knowledge). It's very simple. There are two buttons. If you press win, add 1 score to win variable, if you press lose,  add 1 score to lose variable. And it writes the scores under the buttons. But I can't make it.

```
 </head>

 <body>

   <button id="win">Win!</button><button id="lose">Lose</button>

   </br>

   <script>
     var win = 0;
     var lose = 0;


     function win(){
       win = win + 1;
    };

    function lose (){
      lose = lose + 1
    };
  </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onclick event to your buttons:

```
<button id="win" onclick="return win();">Win!</button>
<button id="lose" onclick="return lose();">Lose</button>
```

You are going to need an element under each button, a div or span, with IDs so that you can change the innerHTML when the numbers are updated. Alter your functions to update the appropriate element.

You also probably want to wrap the buttons and elements in a table.

Comment: sorry but I'm really a starter. What is return mean?

Comment: Functions return a value. You can exit a function using the return statement and optionally pass back a value to the caller. It's a standard practice to use a full statement when specifying events, but not necessary. You could simply use: onclick="loose" .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this-

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><button id="win" onclick="win()">Win!</button></td>
        <td><button id="lose" onclick="lose()">Lose!</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="wins"></td>
         <td id="losses"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
    var wins= 0;
    var losses = 0;

    function win() {
        wins= wins+1;
        document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML= wins;
    };

    function lose() {
        losses= losses+1;
        document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML= losses;
    };
</script>

</html>
```